# php и html передача переменной

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
function reddd($filename){
    $filename = $filename;
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    return $contents;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
      
<body>
    <div class="container" id="blur">
        <div class = "content">
            <h2>psdkhfgdsklfhlsdhfldshflhdslfhsldhf</h2>
            <img src="image.jpg">
            <a href="#" onclick="toggle()">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <h2>asdasdasd</h2>
        <?php echo reddd("test.txt");?>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle()">Close</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle(){
            var blur = document.getElementById('blur');
            blur.classList.toggle('active')
            var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
            popup.classList.toggle('active')
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Меня интересует вывести текст с функции reddd

```
<div id="popup">
        <h2>asdasdasd</h2>
        <?php echo reddd("test.txt");?>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle()">Close</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: я не знаю как передать текст, в php я сделал метод показывающий текст если указать путь до файла, и как это  отобразить в html?

Comment: Ну так у вас метод находится в том же файле с HTML. Метод возвращает строку. Кстати, можно использовать `file_get_content`. Вы делаете `echo`. Значит вы выводите это на экран. Кстати, вместо `php echo` можно использовать `<?= ... ?>`

Comment: Спасибо большое, поискал в интернете и решил проблемы, но ваши советы тоже хороши :)